# Including parent reference in child object with RestKit

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

In RestKit is there an easy way to include a parent reference in a child object? For instance if I have JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "parent": {
        "name": "Jim",
        "child": {
            "name": "John"
        }
    }
}
```

How do I configure the RKObjectMapping such that my "child" object has a "parent" reference (i.e. child.parent)?

Comment: Is this an NSManagedObject or an in memory object?

Comment: Then no. The only way is to modify the source JSON which you can do using the willMapData callback

Comment: Even modifying the JSON, what would I place as the key? I don't believe connecting relationships is supported without managed objects.

Comment: I don't know the structure of your data or what you want to do. If modifying the JSON won't work, capture the objects with didloadobjects, and run through the children objects manually setting the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a decent workaround because this doesn't appear to be directly supported by RestKit.

What you need to do is use key-value validation to place the parent reference into the child object. So, for the above example the Parent model would look something like this:

```
@interface Parent : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Child *child;

@end

@implementation Parent

@synthesize name = _name;
@synthesize child = _child;

- (BOOL)validateChild:(id *)ioValue error:(NSError **)outError
{
    Child *child = (Child *)*ioValue;
    child.parent = self;
    return YES;
}

@end
```